# Echeveria black prince leaves getting soft

Tags: plant-care, succulents

[image]I bought this echeveria about two and half weeks ago from a local nursery. I watered it twice last week. Normally i would water it once a week. Since the time i watered it the bottom leaves feel very soft and slightly mushy. Can you tell me what to do to make sure it doesn't die? I dont see any new growth and when i repotted it i found a few very tiny mealy bugs in the roots. What can i do to get rid of them? I thought of dipping the roots in soap water but given that it's suffering from over watering already, it didn't seem ideal to do that. 
I've placed it in direct sun for 4days now hoping it would help the leaves become normal again. Also, how do i clean the leaves? They have some dirt stuck to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture shows over watering and low phosphorus.  Do not do anything with cleaning the roots, please. Do not water until the pot and plant FEELS lighter than when watered.  The difference in weight is very distinctive.  Do not water until that pot and soil feel light.  Do not water on any schedule. This is a succulent that stores water and even the tiniest bit of too much water will cause rot.

Are you fertilizing with a balanced NPK fertilizer? Too low on phosphorus screams you have not fertilized.  Is this potting soil, sterilized potting medium?  Did you try to enhance drainage by putting gravel or rocks over the drainage hole at the bottom of the pot before you installed the soil and plant?  Very big problem if you did and I'd love to explain to you perched water tables.

This looks to me like over watering and too low on Macro nutrients. No soil even 'rich dark juicy soil' will ever have the proper amounts of NPK and micro nutrients.  Pfft,  unless someone added fertilizer to a bag of potting soil. Don't buy potting soil with fertilizer added or those water holding gimmicks such as sponges and gels!

The color of the leaves denotes phosphorous deficiency. Tells me that you have not used any fertilizer?  Up pot this plant using ONLY sterilized potting soil into a 4" or 6" diameter pot. More shallow than wide, clay is best. Use half the directed amount of fertilizer in the directions of an all purpose fertilizer...such as Osmocote 14-14-14 extended release.  Once or twice per year is enough to provide the chemistry plants have to have to do photosynthesis to make THEIR OWN FOOD. Fertilizer is not food. Compost is not fertilizer nor is it a soil replacement.  How much light does this plant get?  What window?  Don't be moving this plant out of its normal habitat, its normal spot in the light without some direction on acclimation of plants.

Insects will be showing up when you have a weakened and dying plant.  Don't worry about them right now, they are not your problem.  They are a secondary problem easily controlled with NEEM (read those directions!!)

Comment: I repotted it into a shallower plastic mug. I haven't fertilised it. I bought the plant just few weeks back. It's in coco peat only. It's a little hard to find cactus mix or fertilisers like npk in my area. Might take around 15 days for me to get a potting mix and fertiliser because my exams are going on now. There are around 4-5 drainage holes and no rocks or gravel at the bottom. It's placed on the terrace and receives full direct sunlight for around 5 hours minimum. Can the plant wait for 15 days more or do i immediately have to go get fertiliser? And what're water tables?

Comment: 15 days is a long time for any plant. You plant is unable to make the carbohydrates your plant needs for growth and repair.  Perched water tables are made when we humans add chunks of stuff thinking that the gravel, the chips will aid drainage.  Lots of people imagine this to be true but you don't so not to worry, good for you!  Coco peat is NOT a soil replacement nor is it a medium for plant growth.  You need potting soil.  From a bag.  Sterilized no foo foo added.  A basic all purpose fertilizer is critical.  15 days...?  Real soil is critical and then water immediately after potting.

Comment: So if i give the plant proper potting soil with some npk will the leaves get stiffer? I can see wrinkles on the leaves now. It's getting worse..

Comment: When was the last time you watered this plant?  Up pot in proper soil with a tiny bit of fertilizer, proper lighting...not in direct sunlight but bright light and not out of doors either.  Check the roots for mush and rot and brown roots, cut them off, put in potting soil, firm the potting soil and if there is any life left in this plant it will turn around.  Has to have water but shallow and sparse.

Comment: Around 4days ago i watered it. Is there any chance that the bottom leaves that are getting really soft to gain back life? The plant color has gotten darker after 3-4days of sunlight. Do you want me to continue placing it in sunlight or not? The bottom leaves look a little shriveled but not dying

Comment: No, Fariyal, soft, mushy leaves on Echeveria means root rot from too much water.  This is a succulent and succulents store their own water.  A desert plant.  Shallow roots.  Just a little too much water when your plant is fully hydrated, those roots will rot.  Not so much in sterilized soil as there is less bacteria and fungi.  I am worried about moving this plant in and out. Does this plant stay outside all of the time?  What kind of soil did you use?  Moving a plant to different locations can mean death without acclimatization.  This could be sunburn if it wasn't used to full sun.